# How to append a character to a string in Golang?

Tags: string, go, concatenation

How to append a character to a string in Go?

This does not work:

```
s := "hello";
c := 'x'; 
fmt.Println(s + c);
```

*invalid operation: s + c (mismatched types string and rune)*

This does not work either:

```
s := "hello";
c := 'x'; 
fmt.Println(s + rune(c));
```

*invalid operation: s + rune(c) (mismatched types string and rune)*

Comment: Did you post the question and answer at the same time? What for?

Comment: Because I could not find the answer on stack overflow earlier, and google gave shitty results. It is a standard practice.

Comment: I believe that the common practice is to ask questions when you don't know the answer.

Comment: It's not the first time that you post a question adding a few moments later an answer. Use the documentation instead of making question where you already know the answer.

Comment: @slomek If you click on **Ask Question**, you'll see a checkbox **Answer your own question**. This is in fact encouraged by [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), linked from the ask question page.

Comment: What @Tinwor wrote is exactly what I meant. It's OK to answer your own questions, but there is no point of asking one if you **already** have an answer. If you posted it, then worked through it and came up with some solution, I wouldn't mind that.

Comment: @slomek the point of answering your own question is to make a contribution to the knowledge repository that is SO. This is done following the well-established Q&A format. Many of the best posts on this site are self-answers where the OP already knows the answer before the fact and wants to create a clear, canonical resource or dupe target. SO even has a feature described in [ask] to self-answer when asking: "To encourage people to do this, there is a checkbox at the bottom of the page every time you ask a question... Type in your answer, then submit both question and answer together."

Answer (score 100):

In Go rune type is **not** a character type, it is just another name for int32.

If you come from Java or a similar language this will surprise you because Java has char type and you can add char to a string.

```
String s = "hello";
char c = 'x';
System.out.println(s + c);
```

In Go you need to be more explicit:

```
s := "hello";
c := 'x';
fmt.Println(s + string(c));
```

Omg do you really need to convert every char to a string constant? Yes, but do not worry, this is just because of a type system and compiler optimizes it correctly. Under the hood both Java and Go append the char in the same manner.

If you think extra typing sucks, just compare how many times **string** keyword appears in each example above. :)

**Extra info: (technical details)**

In Go strings are **not** sequences of runes, they are **utf-8** encoded sequences of runes. When you range over a string you get runes, but you cannot simply append a rune to a string.
For example: euro sign '€' is an integer 0x20AC (this is called code point)
But when you encode euro sign in utf-8 you get 3 bytes: 0xE2 0x82 0xAC
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20aC/index.htm

So appending a char actually works like this:

```
s = append(s, encodeToUtf8(c)) // Go
s = append(s, encodeToUtf16(c)) // Java
```

Note that encodings are done at compile time.

Utf-8 can encode a character with 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes.
Utf-16 can encode a character with 2 or with 4 bytes.

So Go usually appends 1 byte (for ascii) or 2, 3, 4 bytes for Chinese, and Java usually appends 2 bytes (for ascii) or 4 bytes for Chinese.

Since most characters that we (west) use can be encoded with 2 bytes Java gives the false belief that strings are sequences of 2byte char-s, which is true until you need to encode 美国必须死

Comment: go strings are a sequence of _bytes_, not runes. Ranging over a string implicitly returns runes, along with the byte indexes in the string.

Comment: Actually they are not because not every byte sequence is a valid string.
They can be type casted into sequences of bytes.

Comment: No, I assure you they are (there is no type casting, only conversion). The string data structure consists solely of an array of bytes, and the length that of that array. The range operator scans for runes, but the string is still bytes. The `string` and `[]byte` types have the same underlying data, and can be converted in both directions. https://play.golang.org/p/TBiD44CUI2

Comment: Which makes me wonder, how does range behave with invalid code points?

Comment: @captncraig, the same way it would if you converted the `string` to `[]rune`. You get the replacement character `0xfffd`

Comment: @cohadar: sorry, the phrase "they are utf-8 encoded sequences of runes" was what I found confusing. I though you meant that strings were a representation of `[]rune`, which they are not.

Comment: for i := range "€€€" { fmt.Print(i) } // prints 036

for i := range []byte("€€€") { fmt.Print(i) } // prints 012345678

Comment: @cohadar: that's showing the byte indexes, which exactly what I said and demonstrated in my comment. The same thing without `range` looks like: https://play.golang.org/p/fDjZYSdkIv (and for good measure, the `[]byte` equivalent too https://play.golang.org/p/NgBiQvs4Yr)

Comment: @JimB yes, you are right. I just wanted to point out that even thou "under the hood" some things are same, does not mean type is the same. For example int32 and unit32 are same under the hood but behave differently in sign operations or when printing. Contrast this with int32 and rune which are same both in value and in type (aliases)

Answer (score 15):

**Simple but little inefficient**

While this works perfectly fine for a simple program, But it is a little inefficient. Because strings in Go are immutable , so every time we want to change string or add to string then we are creating new string. For the scenario where we need to add multiple characters/strings to string, then it is inefficient

```
s := "hello";
c := 'x';
fmt.Println(s + string(c));
```

**Using [strings.Builder](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder) (Go 1.10+)**

A Builder is used to efficiently build a string using Write methods. It minimizes memory copying. The zero value is ready to use. Do not copy a non-zero Builder.

```
    package main

    import (
      "strings"
      "fmt"
    )
    
    func main() {
        var s string
        s = "hello";
        var c = 'x';
        var sb strings.Builder
        sb.WriteString(s)
        sb.WriteRune(c)
        fmt.Println(sb.String())
    }
```

https://play.golang.org/p/n1plG9eOxHD

Comment: I'm a bit confused since your code does not really work on the Go playground. For instance, where does `r` come from? The declarations of `s` and `c` aren't syntactically valid Go (unless I'm missing something) but suspiciously like Java. Maybe you wanted something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/06Sa2CfB7JW ?

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn yes, you are right, my bad. Corrected Code syntax

Comment: @ashutosh it's great that you are pointing out the useful strings.Builder type but for simple cases, such as this, I have found that string concatenation is not only more readable but more efficient. Could you please provide benchmarks to back up your claim?